# Pick the maximum element of each nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have a list with nested lists, where each nested list contain entries consisting in 3 columns:

```
t = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {60, 3}];

minx = 0;
maxx = 10;
miny = 0;
maxy = 10;
resx = 5;
resy = 5;
stepx = (maxx - minx)/resx;
stepy = (maxy - miny)/resy;
grid = Table[
   Select[t, 
    minx + stepx*(i - 1) < #[[1]] <= minx + stepx* i && 
      miny + stepy*(j - 1) < #[[2]] <= miny + stepy*j &], {i, 1, 
    resx}, {j, 1, resy} ];
Map[MatrixForm, grid, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Now I want to generate an array of the same size, in this case $5\times 5$ such that each entry contains the row with the maximum value of the third column of the third list. For instance, in this example such an array `MyArray` would have as elements:

```
MyArray[[1,1]]= {1.94367, 1.96706, 5.63112}
MyArray[[1,2]]= {0.706452, 3.92499, 4.00843}
MyArray[[2,1]]= {3.44211, 1.23998, 8.72222}
```

...

```
MyArray[[5,5]]= {9.78142, 8.02858, 4.28738}
```

I know how to pick the maximum element of each sublist, using for instance for the first one:

```
Pick[grid[[1, 1]], #, Max@#] &@grid[[1, 1]][[All, 3]]
```

But I don't know how to apply it simultaneously to all the lists. I guess that is using `Map` somehow, but I cannot figure out how...

Thanks!

Comment: You should post **code** rather than **picture**.

Comment: Have a look at `Max` in *doc*.

Comment: Since there are 9 nested lists I'd expect nine outputs (one maximum for each nested list). Your output has 27. Please explain.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I hope that now after the editing it is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to map your picking function at the second level of the `grid`

```
pick[list_] := Pick[list, #, Max@#] &@list[[All, 3]]
Map[pick, grid, {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Table[RandomReal[10, {RandomInteger[{3, 6}], 3}], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
MatrixForm@Map[MatrixForm, data, {2}]
```

[image]

```
flatter = Flatten[data, 1];
thirdcols = flatter[[All, All, 3]];
max = Max /@ thirdcols;
rowspositions = Flatten@MapThread[Position, {thirdcols, max}];
extracts = Transpose[{Range[9], rowspositions}];
flatter[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ extracts
```

> {{9.96146, 4.95039, 9.12134}, {5.0613, 7.55387, 7.6069}, {9.93072, 
>     9.36066, 6.9762}, {5.37254, 5.64206, 7.42148}, {6.2932, 9.29207, 
>     9.24816}, {6.75852, 0.38891, 9.56726}, {1.96899, 7.40202, 
>     6.87286}, {8.00277, 5.72873, 8.91649}, {4.70735, 5.16466, 8.67289}}

Comment: This procedure doesn't work with the `grid` from the question.

Comment: The OP changed the question after I posted my answer.